# Finding the index of the different words in a list of sentences

Tags: python, string, algorithm, hash, string-matching

An efficient algorithm, that looks at 2 sentences or more, and returns the different word(s) and its index.

> For example:
>
> sentence_a = 'The ***cat*** took the mat.'
>
> sentence_b = 'The ***rat*** took the mat.'
>
> sentence_c = 'The ***cat and rat*** took the mat.'

Here I want to identify the bolded text to be the output.

> `output = [cat, rat, cat and rat]`

I have been researching, but haven't come across anything that would be helpful. I tried to create one, where it compares the words at each index, but when there is an additional word the logic becomes harder to model.

Would appreciate any resources. Thanks!

Comment: Does your dataset or problem sentance are the same, i mean has same words not meaning ?

Comment: @m-zayan Yes the sentences have the same words, except for the different ones that I am trying to capture. The meaning of the sentence does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

First i can tell you your algorithm wont be needing a Machine Learning model , it can be done in classical way

I have a suggestion for you , first thing is that you will **create an array for each sentence , it will store each word of it** , for example :

```
sentence_a = 'The cat took the mat.'
sentence_b = 'The rat took the mat.'
sentence_c = 'The cat and rat took the mat.'
list_a = list()
list_b = list()
list_c = list()
# you will parse each sentence and store the words into the lists
# list_a = [ 'The','cat','took' ... etc ]
# list_b = [ 'The','rat','took' ... etc ]
# ...
```

Then , **you will compare the each one of the lists with the first list** , and each different sentence , will be stored in a third list , for example :

```
list_differences = list() # will store differences
# comparing sentence a and b
for s1,s2 in zip(list_a,list_b):
    if ( s1 != s2 ) :
       list_differences.append( s1 )
       list_differences.append( s2 )

# list_differences = [ 'cat','rat' ]
```

Comment: This is the approach that I was trying to describe in the question. So the problem with this is that when it comes to multiple words, it does not work as this approach is index based and compares index to index. But thanks anyways! Any other approaches are welcome!

Comment: @acho This is not quite simple , i will try to find a solution and add it as another answer , that's an interesting problem by the way

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes I thought it was simple at first, but came across issues as the dataset became more diverse. I was thinking maybe there would be some sort of NLP method to do this sort of thing, but I haven't come across anything yet.

Comment: The ML methods normally doesnt give " exact " results , there is mathematical process there and it gives a certain error and accuracy so we just try to get the summary , like when we want to do a classification , you wont get exactly 1 for a class and 0 for another , it's always like ( 0.75 , 0.25 ) or ( 0.6 , 0.4 ) .. etc , your problem requires more a classic algorithm @acho

Comment: I was thinking about something for you problem , like turning the sentence into a tree where each word is a branch , for example sentence A has 5 branches , and C has 7 branches , so what if we try to find a number of branches in the tree C and we try to compress to map with a branch in A ( mapping the branches [ cat and rat ] with [ cat ] @acho

Comment: That sounds like an interesting approach and definitely something I want to try for my problem! I am not too familiar with tree methods, where could I get more information on this?

Comment: @acho , you can look for data structure and see informations about trees

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of all the words used in the sentences and calculate the inverse document frequency of these terms. The words occurring in every sentence will have an idf of 0 and the different words will have higher idf.
You can keep a separate map of word and sentence index in case exact order of different words is needed in the final array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will give it a try and see what would happens.